# Can't hide canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm writing a code displaying widgets inside canvas then hiding them. The problem is that when I click a button to hide canvas and the widgets, it's not working. Here is the part of code involved:

For placing and showing canvas with widgets:

```
frameContainer = Frame(main, bd=0, bg='white', height=550, width=1265)
canvasResult = Canvas(frameContainer, bd=0, bg='white', height=530, width=1245)
SearchScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frameContainer, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvasResult.yview)
frameResult = Frame(canvasResult, bd=0, bg='white', height=510, width=1225)
canvasResult.create_window((10,10), window=frameResult, anchor=NW)
canvasResult.configure(yscrollcommand=SearchScrollbar.set)
canvasResult.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvasResult.configure(scrollregion = canvasResult.bbox("all"))) 
frameContainer.place(x=400, y=480)
canvasResult.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
SearchScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

and when clicking the button for hiding canvas and the widgets:

```
frameContainer.place_forget()
canvasResult.itemconfigure("highlight", state=tk.HIDDEN)
canvasResult.configure(state='disabled')
canvasResult.pack_forget()
canvasResult.delete("all")
SearchScrollbar.pack_forget()
frameResult.pack_forget()
frameNew.place(x=400, y=210)
```

The new frame (frameNew) is appearing in the background behind the canvas widgets.
Please for your assistance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems working.  Actually the line `frameContainer.place_forget()` hides the frame `frameContainer`, so you don't need to hide the canvas and the scrollbar.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].